# How to write Enums in VB.NET in a COM visible component

Tags: vb.net, com

I am currently written a COM visible component (actually out-of-process exe).

My question is how to properly do Enums.

I simply have this in my Interface

```
<ComVisible(True)> _
Enum TestTypes
    TestType1 = 1
    TestType2 = 2
    TestType3 = 3
End Enum
```

The thing I am seeing is that in the Object Browser each item is TestTypes_TestType1 etc.

[image: Image of what I see in the Browser]
[image: Normally Enums look like this.]

Comment: What else you are expecting to see??

Comment: I have added 2 pictures.  One shows what I see and one shows other enums.

Comment: com callable wrappers are not going to perfectly mirror what you see in .NET when used in COM land, because COM tech is really old and limited in what it can do compared to the managed .net programming environment.  What's wrong with those names?  I don't think there's anything wrong with them...they work, don't they?

Comment: This is the first time I have written a COM Server.  So I dont know if this is correct.  Right now it looks like it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an old, old problem with enums, dates at least as far back as the C language.  A language where enum members get added to the global namespace.  Should be familiar to you, VBA does this as well.  It is a pretty ugly problem, scales very poorly in large programs.  A .NET enum value like `FileShare.Read` can't just be exported as `Read`.  Almost guaranteed to cause a identifier name or keyword collision.

Two basic tricks are used by programmers to avoid such collisions.  Common in C is to upper-case the enum member.  Won't work well in a language like VB of course.  And the other trick is to *prefix* a short string.

A trick that you see being used by the author of the ADODB type library, he prefixed `dbUse`.  And it is the trick you see being used by the .NET library exporter, it prefixes the enum type name.  And it is important that you see yourself using the trick, you prefixed `Test`.  Probably something you did without realizing it, you just got used to it.

But that is no longer appropriate or necessary in VB.NET.  A much more sane way to write that enum is:

```
<ComVisible(True)> _
Enum Test
    Type1 = 1
    Type2 = 2
    Type3 = 3
End Enum
```

And you'd use, say, `Test.Type1` instead of the ugly tautology of `TestTypes.TestType1` in your VB.NET code.

And now the type library exporter produces much more palatable enum member names, like `Test_Type1`.

You cannot otherwise get rid of the underscore without major surgery, you'd have to write the declarations in IDL (like the ADODB author did) and import the type library generated by MIDL back into your program.  Not exactly worth the hassle.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is perfectly normal: the typelib generator of .NET always prefixes enum fields with their respective enum name. If you want to override this behavior, you'll need to edit the fields inside the `IDL` file manually and recreate the type library. See [this](http://blogs.artinsoft.net/mrojas/archive/2010/05/17/interop-remove-prefix-from-c-enums-for-com.aspx) link for further details.

Comment: Thank you Aurora, my Google searches did not find that link which would have saved me a question if I had.